# Adjusting a view for keyboard appearing/disappearing: problem with animation curve

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to create a SwiftUI view modifier that adds bottom padding in response to the on-screen keyboard appearing or disappearing. This is the approach I'm using:

```
struct KeyboardAdjustingModifier: ViewModifier {
    @ObservedObject private var responder = KeyboardResponder()

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            content
                .padding(.bottom, self.bottomPadding(in: proxy))
        }
    }

    func bottomPadding(in proxy: GeometryProxy) -> CGFloat {
        if responder.endFrame == .zero {
            return 0
        } else {
            return max(0, proxy.frame(in: .global).maxY - self.responder.endFrame.minY)
        }
    }
}

fileprivate final class KeyboardResponder: ObservableObject {
    @Published var endFrame: CGRect = .zero

    init(notificationCenter: NotificationCenter = .default) {
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(keyboardWillShowOrChangeFrame(notification:)),
                                       name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(keyboardWillShowOrChangeFrame(notification:)),
                                       name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)),
                                       name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc private func keyboardWillShowOrChangeFrame(notification: Notification) {
        withAnimation(Animation(curve: notification.animationCurve, duration: notification.duration)) {
            endFrame = notification.endFrame
        }
    }

    @objc private func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
        withAnimation(Animation(curve: notification.animationCurve, duration: notification.duration)) {
            endFrame = .zero
        }
    }

    struct Info {
        let curve: UIView.AnimationCurve
        let duration: TimeInterval
        let endFrame: CGRect
    }
}

fileprivate extension Animation {
    init(curve: UIView.AnimationCurve, duration: TimeInterval) {
        switch curve {
        case .easeInOut:
            self = .easeInOut(duration: duration)
        case .easeIn:
            self = .easeIn(duration: duration)
        case .easeOut:
            self = .easeOut(duration: duration)
        case .linear:
            self = .linear(duration: duration)
        @unknown default:
            self = .easeInOut(duration: duration)
        }
    }
}

fileprivate extension Notification {
    var animationCurve: UIView.AnimationCurve {
        guard let rawValue = (userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? Int) else {
            return UIView.AnimationCurve.linear
        }

        return UIView.AnimationCurve(rawValue: rawValue)!
    }

    var duration: TimeInterval {
        userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? TimeInterval ?? 0
    }

    var endFrame: CGRect {
        userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect ?? .zero
    }
}
```

The problem I'm running in to is that it seems as though the SwiftUI animation curve is quite different from the keyboard's animation curve:

[image: Animation curve mismatch]

Does anyone know if it's possible to sync up a SwiftUI animation with UIKit like this? It's quite possible there is an error in how I'm mapping the animation curve info from the notification's `userInfo` to a SwiftUI animation curve. Or is there a different approach to this problem altogether that I ought to consider?

One other thing I tried is using a `UIHostingController` that handles the animation directly in UIKit. It synced up properly with the keyboard, but I ran into crashes when calling `layoutIfNeeded` in my animation blocks if SwiftUI was also animating stuff at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'm using and it works almost perfectly:

### Demo

[image: demo]

### Code

```swift
public extension View {
    func adaptToKeyboard() -> some View {
        modifier(AdaptToSoftwareKeyboard())
    }
}

public struct AdaptToSoftwareKeyboard: ViewModifier {
    @State var currentHeight: CGFloat = 0

    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding(.bottom, currentHeight)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
            .animation(.spring())
            .onAppear(perform: subscribeToKeyboardEvents)
    }

    private func subscribeToKeyboardEvents() {
        NotificationCenter.Publisher(
            center: NotificationCenter.default,
            name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification
        )
            .compactMap { $0.userInfo?["UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey"] as? CGRect }
            .map { $0.height }
            .subscribe(Subscribers.Assign(object: self, keyPath: \.currentHeight))

        NotificationCenter.Publisher(
            center: NotificationCenter.default,
            name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification
        )
            .compactMap { _ in CGFloat.zero }
            .subscribe(Subscribers.Assign(object: self, keyPath: \.currentHeight))
    }
}
```

### Usage

```swift
someView()
    .adaptToKeyboard()
```

Test it with the demo here: https://github.com/youjinp/SwiftUIKit

Comment: seems doesn't work in iOS 16